# How to correctly set up l3build

Tags: l3build

I am currently trying to start writing a package and `l3build` seems to be a rather useful tool for this. I have read up on how to write `.ins` and `.dtx` files as well as the documentation for `l3build`. As far as I could tell, a minimal setup for a new package would be a folder containing the following three files.

- #### `testpackage.dtx`

  ```
  % \iffalse meta-comment
  %
  % Some notes about the package.
  % See for example siunitx.dtx for an example.
  %
  %<*driver>
  \documentclass{l3doc}
  % The next line is needed so that \GetFileInfo will be able to pick up
  % version data
  \usepackage{testpackage}
  \begin{document}
    \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
  \end{document}
  %</driver>
  % \fi
  %
  % \GetFileInfo{testpackage.sty}
  %
  % \title{^^A
  %   \pkg{testpackage} -- Just for testing purposes!^^A
  %   \thanks{This file describes \fileversion,
  %     last revised \filedate.}^^A
  % }
  %
  % \author{^^A
  %  Someone^^A
  %  \thanks{^^A
  %    E-mail:
  %    \href{mailto:foo@bar.baz}
  %      {foo@bar.baz}^^A
  %   }^^A
  % }
  %
  % \date{Released \filedate}
  %
  % \maketitle
  %
  % \begin{documentation}
  %
  % \section{\cs{foo} is a function}
  % \begin{function}{\foo}
  %   \begin{syntax}
  %     |\foo| \marg{input}
  %   \end{syntax}
  %   Something about \cs{foo}.
  %   |\foo{bar}| will produce `\foo{bar}'.
  % \end{function}
  %
  % \end{documentation}
  %
  % \begin{implementation}
  %
  % \section{Implementation}
  %
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  %<*package>
  %    \end{macrocode}
  %
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  %<@@=testpackage>
  %    \end{macrocode}
  %
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  \RequirePackage{xparse}
  \ProvidesExplPackage {testpackage} {2019-06-23} {0.1.0}
                   {Just for testing purposes!}
  %    \end{macrocode}
  %
  % \begin{macro}{\foo}
  %   \begin{arguments}
  %     \item Some input
  %   \end{arguments}
  %   Some description of \cs{foo}
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  \NewDocumentCommand \foo { m }
    {
      I~saw~#1!
    }
  %    \end{macrocode}
  % \end{macro}
  %
  %    \begin{macrocode}
  %</package>
  %    \end{macrocode}
  %
  % \end{implementation}
  %
  % \PrintIndex
  ```
- #### `testpackage.ins`

  ```
  \iffalse meta-comment

  Info about the package.

  \fi

  \input l3docstrip.tex
  \askforoverwritefalse
  \keepsilent

  \preamble
  This is the preamble!
  \endpreamble
  \postamble
  This is the postamble!
  \endpostamble

  \generate
    {%
      \file{testpackage.sty}
        {%
          \from{testpackage.dtx}{package}
        }%
    }

  \endbatchfile
  ```
- #### `build.lua`

  ```lua
  -- Build script for the testpackage package.

  -- Identify the module.
  module = "testpackage"
  ```

Running `l3build unpack` seems to work fine and creates some folders containing the unpacked `.sty` file. However, trying to run `l3build doc` leads to the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: File `testpackage.sty' not found.
```

- What do I have to change in the setup to be able to produce documentation using `l3build`?
- Are there any other obvious steps I should include in this setup in order to avoid similar problems using the other `l3build` later (in particular `check` and `ctan`)?
- Say I want to have a test document (not a test file for `l3build`) in which I can play around with the current development state of the package (without installing it in my texmf tree; unrelated documents should *not* find the development version of the package). Is there a convenient way to do this? Or do I have to manually copy the unpacked `.sty` file to some separate folder in order to test it in this way?

Comment: Are you sure you have everything exactly as described? I just checked with your files for `l3build doc` and, as expected, it's all OK.

Comment: @JosephWright I am. Created new files and copied them from here just to be sure. My `l3build` has the release date `2019-06-18`, so that shouldn't be the issue either. My MiKTeX is up to date as well. Anything else I should check?

Comment: where exactly do you have the files?

Comment: In a folder on my desktop.

Comment: I didn't expect it to be in your wardroom. What is the path of the folder?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ooh, good instincts. It was `c:\Users\firstname lastname\Desktop\temp\l3doctest\`. In a folder without any spaces in the path it works. Is this a bug or just an undocumented inconvenience?

Comment: Issue with spaces logged as https://github.com/latex3/l3build/issues/91: I think I see the problem.

Comment: Space handling is fixed and will be to CTAN shortly

Comment: If anybody else is coming here via google, @pablgonz has a nice demo on github https://github.com/pablgonz/demopkg-jw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the three parts

- The set up you have should be correct with a recent `l3build`, at least for the minimal sources you've got
- All steps in `l3build` use the same data, so once you have the `doc` target working then `check` and `ctan` will be the same
- You have a few options for a test document. You could simply have it in the working folder and add it to `typesetfiles` or `typesetdemofiles`. You could use the `--texmfhome` option to use a custom install location: this works best if you use `TEXINPUTS` or `auxtrees` to set up additional inputs. Or you could as you say simply unpack and then copy manually.